# Pandas-Update previous and next rows value based on current row value group by Id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe, df and want to change the value in column 'Status' for each 'Id'

The rule is:
If 'Status' == 'High' update rows before to 'Before' Else 'After'

The dataframe, df:

```
     Id     Status    
0    1      Low
1    1      Low
2    1      High
3    1      Low
4    2      Low
5    2      Low
6    2      High
7    2      Low
8    3      Low
9    3      Low
10   3      High
11   3      Low
12   3      High
13   3      Low
```

My expected df:

```
     Id     Status
 0   1      Before
 1   1      Before
 2   1      High
 3   1      After
 4   2      Before
 5   2      Before
 6   2      High
 7   2      After
 8   3      Before
 9   3      Before
10   3      High
11   3      After
12   3      High
13   3      After
```

This is my code so far, (I have not added the rule else change to 'After' yet)

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Id'])['Status'] == "High", df['Status'].shift(1)] = 'Before'
```

I got an error:

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Comment: for index 11 onwards how come `Before` takes precedence over  `After`, technically both 11 and 13 follow a `High`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for set after last `High` per groups to `After` and all values with no `High` to `Before`:

```
m1 = df['Status'].eq('High')
m2 = m1.groupby(df['Id']).cumsum() == 0

df['Status1'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['High', 'Before'], default='After') 
print (df)
    Id Status Status1
0    1    Low  Before
1    1    Low  Before
2    1   High    High
3    1    Low   After
4    2    Low  Before
5    2    Low  Before
6    2   High    High
7    2    Low   After
8    3    Low  Before
9    3    Low  Before
10   3   High    High
11   3    Low   After
12   3   High    High
13   3    Low   After
```

Comment: not expected output if you look close, OP output is a little confusing

Comment: Yeah, the OP output is confusing here. I'll edit the OP output.

Comment: @noishi - OK, added original solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function:

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].map({'High': 'After', 'Low': 'Before'})
```

Comment: No, do you check output?